# Refreshing checkbox state in a listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have list view with custom row layout (list_row.xml) that contains CheckBox element:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1.0">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_weight=".85"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="sample"
            android:textSize="24sp">
        </TextView>
        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/enabled"
            android:layout_weight=".15"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:focusable="false">
        </CheckBox>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

In my list activity I've got ListRowAdapter:

```
private static class ListRowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListRow> implements
        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private List<ListRow> items;
    private LayoutInflater vi;
    private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;

    public ListRowAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<ListRow> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.items = objects;
        this.vi = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(objects.size());
        for(int i=0;i<mCheckStates.size();i++){
            mCheckStates.put(i,items.get(i).isEnabled());
        }
        Log.i("VIEW", "constructor");
    }

    public boolean isChecked(int position) {
        return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
    }

    public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
        mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
        items.get(position).setEnabled(isChecked);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void toggle(int position) {
        setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
    }

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        ListRow r = (ListRow) buttonView.getTag();
        r.setEnabled(isChecked);
        mCheckStates.put(items.indexOf(r), isChecked);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "row " + r.getName() + " changed to "+isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            Log.i("VIEW", "init holder");
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.enabled = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.enabled);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            Log.i("VIEW", "using holder");
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        ListRow row = items.get(position);
        if (row != null) {
            holder.name.setText(row.getName());
            holder.enabled.setTag(row);
            holder.enabled.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));           holder.enabled.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        CheckBox enabled;
    }

}
```

In my Activity (that extends ListActivity) I do the following:

```
private static List<ListRow> rows;
private ListRowAdapter lra;
```

... and then

```
getListView().setItemsCanFocus(false);
getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
rows = initRows();
lra = new ListRowAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, rows);
setListAdapter(lra);
```

and that works fine while scrolling. But if I don't use `mCheckStates` array it fails! I just can't understand why. I have items array as a member of my Activity class and it contains all the states of checkboxes! I update it in `onCheckedChanged()` method like I update `mCheckState`. So the following code has to work:

```
public boolean isChecked(int position) {
    return items.get(position).isEnebled();
}

public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
    items.get(position).setEnabled(isChecked);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void toggle(int position) {
    setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
}

public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    ListRow r = (ListRow) buttonView.getTag();
    r.setEnabled(isChecked);
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "row " + r.getName() + " changed to "+isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and in `getView()` method:

```
holder.enabled.setTag(row);holder.enabled.setChecked(row.isEnabled());
```

But it doesn't. It loses checkbox states while scrolling and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I followed everything you said there, but keep in mind that `ListView` recycles views as you scroll.  This means that you cannot assume that a view will be in any default state at the start of `getView`.  This is probably why it doesn't work when you stop resetting the checkbox to the correct state every time you get a new view.

That said, did you consider using `ListView`s built in checkbox tool?  Set its choice mode to [CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE) and use one of their provided layouts, like `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice`.

Comment: In my view declaration I have android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" (is that what you meant?) and....unfortunately I can't use simple_list_item_multiple_choice because I've got very comlicated row layout. Different from example below

Comment: Ok, you should still be able to allow Android to handle tracking which CheckBoxes are checked by using a CheckedTextView with id @android:id/text1 in your layout where you want the checkbox.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you... You meant using CheckedTextView instead of CheckBox?

Comment: Well, I looked at the layouts simple_list_* and they all have a CheckedTextView with id @android:id/text1 . I think the id is the important part.  I'd try that first, and if it works, try switching it to a CheckBox and see if it still does.

Answer (score 1):

What I have found is that because getView is redrawing and recycling the list item on scroll one needs to state explicitly when the check box should be checked and when not (similar solution for the selected item's background colour) in a statment like

if (condition){...set check box checked code...}else{...set check box unchecked code...}

The checkbox state can be derived from an array which must be updated every time the user check or uncheck the box in the list view.